# Analyzing patient treatment data using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-mining

I work in the population health industry and get contracts from commercial companies to conduct research on their products. This is the general code to identify target patient groups from a provincial datasets, including DAD (hospital discharge), PC (physician claims), NACRS (emergency room visit), PIN (drug dispensation), and REG (provincial registry). Same patients can have multiple rows in each of the databases. For example, if a patient was hospitalized 3 times, s/he will show up as three separate rows in DAD data. The code does the followings:

1. Import data from csv files into individual Pandas dataframes (df's)
2. Then it goes through some initial data cleaning and processing (such as random sampling, date formatting, calling additional reference information (such as icd code for study condition)
3. Under the section `1) Identify patients for case defn'n #1`, a series of steps have been done to label (as tags) each of the relevant data and filtering based on these tags. Datasets are linked together to see if a particular patient fulfills the diagnostic code requirement.
4. Information also needs to be aggregated by unique patient level via the `pivot_table` function to summarize by unique patients
5. At the end, the final patient dataframe is saved into local directory, and analytic results are printed
6. I also made my own modules `feature_tagger` to house some of the more frequently-used functions away from this main code

```
# Overall steps:
# 1) Patient defintiion: Had a ICD code and a procedure code within a time period
# 2) Output: A list of PHN_ENC of included patients; corresponding index date
    # .. 'CaseDefn1_PatientDict_FINAL.txt'
    # .. 'CaseDefn1_PatientDf_FINAL.csv'
# 3) Results: Analytic results
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import pandas as pd
import datetime
import random
import feature_tagger.feature_tagger as ft
import data_descriptor.data_descriptor as dd
import data_transformer.data_transformer as dt
import var_creator.var_creator as vc

# Unrestrict pandas' output display
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 120)

# Control panel
save_file_switch = False # WARNING: will overwrite existing when == True
df_subsampling_switch = False # WARNING: make to sure turn off for final results
edge_date_inclusion = True # whether to include the last date in the range of inclusion criteria
testing_printout_switch = False
result_printout_switch = True
done_switch = True
df_subsampling_n = 15000
random_seed = 888

# Instantiate objects
ft_obj = ft.Tagger()
dt_obj = dt.Data_Transformer()

# Import data
loc = 'office'
if loc == 'office':
    directory = r'E:\My_Working_Primary\Projects\Data_Analysis\\'
elif loc == 'home':
    directory = r'C:\Users\MyStuff\Dropbox\Projects\Data_Analysis\\'
else: pass

refDataDir = r'_Data\RefData\\'
realDataDir = r'_Data\RealData\\'
resultDir = r'_Results\\'

file_dad = 'Prepped_DAD_Data.csv'
file_pc = 'Prepped_PC_Data.csv'
file_nacrs = 'Prepped_NACRS_Data.csv'
file_pin = 'Prepped_PIN_Data.csv'
file_reg = 'Prepped_REG_Data.csv'

df_dad = pd.read_csv(directory+realDataDir+file_dad, dtype={'PHN_ENC': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_pc = pd.read_csv(directory+realDataDir+file_pc, dtype={'PHN_ENC': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_nacrs = pd.read_csv(directory+realDataDir+file_nacrs, dtype={'PHN_ENC': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_pin = pd.read_csv(directory+realDataDir+file_pin, dtype={'PHN_ENC': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_reg = pd.read_csv(directory+realDataDir+file_reg, dtype={'PHN_ENC': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)

# Create random sampling of df's to run codes faster
if df_subsampling_switch==True:
    if (df_subsampling_n>len(df_dad))|(df_subsampling_n>len(df_pc))|(df_subsampling_n>len(df_nacrs))|(df_subsampling_n>len(df_pin)):
        print ('Warning: Specified subsample size is larger than the total no. of row of some of the dataset,')
        print ('As a result, resampling with replacement will be done to reach specified subsample size.')
    df_dad = dt_obj.random_n(df_dad, n=df_subsampling_n, on_switch=df_subsampling_switch, random_state=random_seed)
    df_pc = dt_obj.random_n(df_pc, n=df_subsampling_n, on_switch=df_subsampling_switch, random_state=random_seed)
    df_nacrs = dt_obj.random_n(df_nacrs, n=df_subsampling_n, on_switch=df_subsampling_switch, random_state=random_seed)
    df_pin = dt_obj.random_n(df_pin, n=df_subsampling_n, on_switch=df_subsampling_switch, random_state=random_seed)

# Format variable type
df_dad['ADMIT_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dad['ADMIT_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_dad['DIS_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_dad['DIS_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_pc['SE_END_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pc['SE_END_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_pc['SE_START_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pc['SE_START_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_nacrs['ARRIVE_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_nacrs['ARRIVE_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_pin['DSPN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_pin['DSPN_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df_reg['PERS_REAP_END_RSN_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df_reg['PERS_REAP_END_RSN_DATE'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Import reference codes
file_rxCode = '_InStudyCodes_ATC&DIN.csv'
file_icdCode = '_InStudyCodes_DxICD.csv'
file_serviceCode = '_InStudyCodes_ServiceCode.csv'

df_rxCode = pd.read_csv(directory+refDataDir+file_rxCode, dtype={'ICD_9': str}, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_icdCode = pd.read_csv(directory+refDataDir+file_icdCode, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)
df_serviceCode = pd.read_csv(directory+refDataDir+file_serviceCode, encoding='utf-8', low_memory=False)

# Defining study's constant variables
inclusion_start_date = datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 00, 00, 00) 
inclusion_end_date = datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 31, 23, 59, 59)

sp_serviceCode_dict = {df_serviceCode['Short_Desc'][0]:df_serviceCode['Health_Service_Code'][0]}
sp_serviceCode_val = sp_serviceCode_dict['ABC injection']

sp_dxCode_dict = {'DIABETES_ICD9': df_icdCode['ICD_9'][0], 'DIABETES_ICD10': df_icdCode['ICD_10'][0]}
sp_dxCode_val_icd9 = sp_dxCode_dict['DIABETES_ICD9']
sp_dxCode_val_icd10 = sp_dxCode_dict['DIABETES_ICD10']

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# 1) Identify patients for case def'n #1.
# Step 1 - Aged between 18 and 100 years old on the index date
# Step 2 - Had at least 1 recorded ICD diagnostic code based on physician visit (ICD-9-CA=9999 in PC) or 
    # hospitalization (ICD-10-CA=G9999 in DAD) during the inclusion period
# Step 3.1 - Had at least 1 specific procedure code (99.999O) during 
    # the inclusion period (Note: earliest ABC injection code date is the Index date)
# Step 3.2 - Construct index date
# Step 4 - Registered as a valid Alberta resident for 2 years before the index date and 1 year after the 
    # index date (determined from PR)

# 1.1) Get age at each service, then delete rows with age falling out of 18-100 range
df_dad_ageTrimmed = df_dad.copy()
df_dad_ageTrimmed = df_dad_ageTrimmed[(df_dad_ageTrimmed['AGE']>=18) & (df_dad_ageTrimmed['AGE']<=100)]

df_pc_ageTrimmed = df_pc.copy()
df_pc_ageTrimmed = df_pc_ageTrimmed[(df_pc_ageTrimmed['AGE']>=18) & (df_pc_ageTrimmed['AGE']<=100)]

# 1.2) Tag appropriate date within sp range > tag DIABETES code > combine tags
df_dad_ageTrimmed['DAD_DATE_TAG'] = ft_obj.date_range_tagger(df_dad_ageTrimmed, 'ADMIT_DATE', 
    start_date_range=inclusion_start_date, end_date_range=inclusion_end_date, edge_date_inclusion=
    edge_date_inclusion)
df_dad_ageTrimmed['DAD_ICD_TAG'] = ft_obj.multi_var_cond_tagger(df_dad_ageTrimmed, repeat_var_base_name='DXCODE', 
    repeat_var_start=1, repeat_var_end=25, cond_list=[sp_dxCode_val_icd10])
df_dad_ageTrimmed['DAD_DATE_ICD_TAG'] = ft_obj.summing_all_tagger(df_dad_ageTrimmed, tag_var_list=['DAD_DATE_TAG', 
    'DAD_ICD_TAG'])

df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_DATE_TAG'] = ft_obj.date_range_tagger(df_pc_ageTrimmed, 'SE_END_DATE', 
    start_date_range=inclusion_start_date, end_date_range=inclusion_end_date, edge_date_inclusion=
    edge_date_inclusion)
df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_ICD_TAG'] = ft_obj.multi_var_cond_tagger(df_pc_ageTrimmed, repeat_var_base_name='HLTH_DX_ICD9X_CODE_', 
    repeat_var_start=1, repeat_var_end=3, cond_list=[str(sp_dxCode_val_icd9)])
df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_DATE_ICD_TAG'] = ft_obj.summing_all_tagger(df_pc_ageTrimmed, tag_var_list=['PC_DATE_TAG', 
    'PC_ICD_TAG'])

# Output a list of all patients PHN_ENC who satisfy the Date and DIABETES code criteria
df_dad_ageDateICDtrimmed = df_dad_ageTrimmed[df_dad_ageTrimmed['DAD_DATE_ICD_TAG']==1]
df_pc_ageDateICDtrimmed = df_pc_ageTrimmed[df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_DATE_ICD_TAG']==1]

dad_patientList_diabetes_Code = df_dad_ageDateICDtrimmed['PHN_ENC'].unique().tolist()
pc_patientList_diabetes_Code = df_pc_ageDateICDtrimmed['PHN_ENC'].unique().tolist()
dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_Code = list(set(dad_patientList_diabetes_Code)|set(pc_patientList_diabetes_Code))
dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_Code.sort()

# 1.3.1) Tag appropriate date within sp range > tag ABC injection code > combine tags
df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_PROC_TAG'] = df_pc_ageTrimmed['ABC_INJECT']
df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_DATE_PROC_TAG'] = ft_obj.summing_all_tagger(df_pc_ageTrimmed, tag_var_list=['PC_DATE_TAG', 
    'PC_PROC_TAG'])
df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed = df_pc_ageTrimmed[df_pc_ageTrimmed['PC_DATE_PROC_TAG']==1]

pc_patientList_procCode = df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed['PHN_ENC'].unique().tolist()
dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_NprocCode = list(set(dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_Code)&set(pc_patientList_procCode))
dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_NprocCode.sort()

# 1.3.2) Find Index date
df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed, index=['PHN_ENC'], 
    values=['SE_END_DATE', 'AGE', 'SEX', 'RURAL'], aggfunc={'SE_END_DATE':np.min, 'AGE':np.min,
    'SEX':'first', 'RURAL':'first'})
df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot = pd.DataFrame(df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot.to_records())
df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot = df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot.rename(columns={'SE_END_DATE':'INDEX_DT'})

# 1.4) Filter by valid registry
# Create a list variable (based on index date) to indicate which fiscal years need to be valid according to
    # the required 2 years before index and 1 year after index date, in df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot
def extract_needed_fiscal_years(row): # extract 2 years before and 1 year after index date
    if int(row['INDEX_DT'].month) >= 4:
        index_yr = int(row['INDEX_DT'].year)+1
    else: 
        index_yr = int(row['INDEX_DT'].year)
    first_yr = index_yr-2
    four_yrs_str = str(first_yr)+','+str(first_yr+1)+','+str(first_yr+2)+','+str(first_yr+3)
    return four_yrs_str

df_temp = df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot.copy()
df_temp['FYE_NEEDED'] = df_temp.apply(extract_needed_fiscal_years, axis=1)
df_temp['FYE_NEEDED'] = df_temp['FYE_NEEDED'].apply(lambda x: x[0:].split(',')) # from whole string to list of string items
df_temp['FYE_NEEDED'] = df_temp['FYE_NEEDED'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x]) # from list of string items to list of int items

# Create a list variable to indicate the active fiscal year, in df_reg
df_reg['FYE_ACTIVE'] = np.where(df_reg['ACTIVE_COVERAGE']==1, df_reg['FYE'], np.nan)
df_reg_agg = df_reg.groupby(by='PHN_ENC').agg({'FYE_ACTIVE':lambda x: list(x)})
df_reg_agg = df_reg_agg.reset_index()
df_reg_agg['FYE_ACTIVE'] = df_reg_agg['FYE_ACTIVE'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if ~np.isnan(i)]) # remove float nan
df_reg_agg['FYE_ACTIVE'] = df_reg_agg['FYE_ACTIVE'].apply(lambda x: [int(i) for i in x]) # convert float to int

# Merge df's and create tag, if active years do not cover all the required fiscal year, exclude patients
# Create inclusion/exclusion patient list to apply to obtain patient cohort based on case def'n #1
df_temp_v2 = df_temp.merge(df_reg_agg, on='PHN_ENC', how='left')
df_temp_v2_trimmed = df_temp_v2[(df_temp_v2['FYE_NEEDED'].notnull())&(df_temp_v2['FYE_ACTIVE'].notnull())]
# Remove rows with missing on either variables

def compare_list_elements_btw_cols(row):
    if set(row['FYE_NEEDED']).issubset(row['FYE_ACTIVE']):
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

df_temp_v2_trimmed['VALID_REG'] = df_temp_v2_trimmed.apply(compare_list_elements_btw_cols, axis=1)
df_temp_v2_trimmed_v2 = df_temp_v2_trimmed[df_temp_v2_trimmed['VALID_REG']==1]
reg_patientList = df_temp_v2_trimmed_v2['PHN_ENC'].unique().tolist()

# Apply inclusion/exclusion patient list (from REG) to find final patients
# Obtain final patient list
df_final_defn1 = df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot.merge(df_temp_v2_trimmed_v2, on='PHN_ENC', how='inner')
df_final_defn1 = df_final_defn1[['PHN_ENC', 'AGE_x', 'SEX_x', 'RURAL_x', 'INDEX_DT_x']]
df_final_defn1 = df_final_defn1.rename(columns={'AGE_x':'AGE', 'SEX_x':'SEX', 'RURAL_x':'RURAL', 'INDEX_DT_x':'INDEX_DT',})
df_final_defn1['PREINDEX_1Yr'] = (df_final_defn1['INDEX_DT']-pd.Timedelta(days=364)) # 364 because index date is counted as one pre-index date
df_final_defn1['PREINDEX_2Yr'] = (df_final_defn1['INDEX_DT']-pd.Timedelta(days=729)) # 729 because index date is counted as one pre-index date
df_final_defn1['POSTINDEX_1Yr'] = (df_final_defn1['INDEX_DT']+pd.Timedelta(days=364))

list_final_defn1 = df_final_defn1['PHN_ENC'].unique().tolist()
dict_final_defn1 = {'Final unique patients of case definition #1':list_final_defn1}

# Additional ask (later on)
# How: Create INDEX_DT_FIS_YR (index date fiscal year) by mapping INDEX_DT to fiscal year
def index_date_fiscal_year(row):
    if ((row['INDEX_DT'] >= datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 1, 00, 00, 00)) &
        (row['INDEX_DT'] < datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 00, 00, 00))):
        return '2015/2016'
    elif ((row['INDEX_DT'] >= datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 1, 00, 00, 00)) &
        (row['INDEX_DT'] < datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 1, 00, 00, 00))):
        return '2016/2017'
    else:
        return 'Potential error'

df_final_defn1['INDEX_DT_FIS_YR'] = df_final_defn1.apply(index_date_fiscal_year, axis=1)

# 2) Output final patient list for future access
# WARNING: will overwrite existing
if save_file_switch == True:
    if df_subsampling_switch == True:
        f = open(directory+resultDir+'_CaseDefn1_PatientDict_Subsample.txt',"w")
        f.write(str(dict_final_defn1)+',')
        f.close()
        df_final_defn1.to_csv(directory+resultDir+'_CaseDefn1_PatientDf_Subsample.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
    elif df_subsampling_switch == False:
        f = open(directory+resultDir+'CaseDefn1_PatientDict_FINAL.txt',"w")
        f.write(str(dict_final_defn1)+',')
        f.close()
        df_final_defn1.to_csv(directory+resultDir+'CaseDefn1_PatientDf_FINAL.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8')

# 3) Results: Analytic results
if result_printout_switch == True:
    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100 during inclusion period) from DAD:')
    print (df_dad_ageTrimmed['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100 during inclusion period) from PC:')
    print (df_pc_ageTrimmed['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100 during inclusion period) from DAD or PC:')
    dd_obj = dd.Data_Comparator(df_dad_ageTrimmed, df_pc_ageTrimmed, 'PHN_ENC')
    print (dd_obj.unique_n_union())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100) and (had DIABETES code during inclusion period) from DAD:')
    print (df_dad_ageDateICDtrimmed['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100) and (had DIABETES code during inclusion period) from PC:')
    print (df_pc_ageDateICDtrimmed['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100) and (had DIABETES code during inclusion period) from DAD or PC:')
    print (len(dad_pc_patientList_diabetes_Code))

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 100) and (had DIABETES code during inclusion period)\
and (had ABC injection code) from DAD and PC:')
    print (df_pc_ageDateProcTrimmed_pivot['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    print ('Unique PHN_ENC N, (aged 18 to 1005) and (had DIABETES code during inclusion period)\
and (had ABC injection code) and (had AB resident around index date) from DAD, PC, and REG [Case Def #1]:')
    print (df_final_defn1['PHN_ENC'].nunique())

    # Additional analytic ask (later on)
    print ('Patient N by index date as corresponding fiscal year:')
    print (df_final_defn1['INDEX_DT_FIS_YR'].value_counts())

if done_switch == True:
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, b'Hello there', b'Program done.', 3)
```

My questions are:

- This is a code for a specific project, other projects from other companies while aren't exactly the same, they usually follow similar overall steps including cleaning data, linking data, creating tags, filtering tags,  aggregating data, saving files, and producing data. How can I refactor my code to be maintainable within this specific project, as well as reusable across similar projects?
- Many times, once I have run the code and produce the results, clients may come back to ask for additional follow-up information (i.e., the ones under `# Additional ask (later on)`). How can I deal with additional asks more effectively with maintainability and expandability in mind?
- Any areas I can try using some design patterns?
- Any other suggestions on how I can write better python code are more than welcome.

Comment: Your original title said "big data". That doesn't seem to apply, since you're dealing with hundreds of rows, rather than millions.

Comment: Nope, my full datasets normally reached millions of rows. That's why I need the `df_subsampling_switch` to sample data for code development. Another characteristic that deems this problem to be big data is that they are linkable, which created a lot more complexity.

Comment: Sorry, I made a wrong assumption based on `pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)`.

Comment: No worries. that's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, most or all of your "projects" follow the same format, even if they use different files and look for different data in different fields.

That says to me that you should try to squeeze out the repeated parts into various helpers, and try to put the boilerplate parts into some sort of common framework.

(Note: it looks like you are using Dropbox, and I suspect you're using it to move those files from the office to home. I don't know if you're paying for your dropbox or just using the free version, and I suspect that dropbox is probably better at security than most. But please [be careful.](https://blog.acolyer.org/2019/04/08/how-bad-can-it-git-characterizing-secret-leakage-in-public-github-repositories/)

### Create a module for configuration data and setup

Have a look at the help available from the `pip install --help` command, specifically the `-e (--editable)` option. This allows you to install from a directory or URL.

This will allow you to create a module that detects your home/office setup (if hostname == 'MY-PC': ... home ... else: ... office ...) and makes whatever configuration is appropriate. Then you can do something like:

```
from kubik88 import Config
from kubik88.data_analysis import *
```

(Doing the `import *` allows you to import functions and classes from other modules-- just set your `__all__` correctly.)

### Use the *template method* pattern

Create a class. Then create a [**template method**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method) on that class that summarizes your effort at the highest level. I'm basing mine off the text of your comments, and I stopped after a few steps because I hope you get the idea:

```
class PatientDataAnalysis:

    def analysis(self):
        self.instantiate_objects()
        self.import_data()
        self.random_sample_dataframes()
        self.update_column_formats()
        self.import_reference_codes()
        self.define_constant_variables()
        ...
```

Notice I'm not doing any work, just calling some methods to do "primitive" operations.

Next, define methods to do the primitive things:

```
# Waaaay up at the top:
import pathlib

    def import_data(self):
        ''' Import all the project data into dataframes. '''
        for abbr, filename in self.data_files.items():
            self.import_csv(abbr, filename)

    def import_csv(self, abbr, filename, **kwargs):
        ''' Import one CSV file into a dataframe, and store it in 
            `self.dataframes` keyed by abbr. 
        '''
        options = (self.read_csv_options if not kwargs
                   else { **self.read_csv_options, **kwargs })
        filespec = self.base_path / self.real_data / filename
        df = pd.read_csv(str(filespec), **options)
        self.dataframes[abbr] = df
```

With this approach, you can now subclass the parent class and extend the methods that you care about, leaving the default behavior where you don't care (or where it just works):

```
class DiabetesStudy2019(PatientDataAnalysis):
    def import_data(self):
        # Do the usual stuff
        super().import_data()
        # And also do one more thing:
        ...
```

### Use helper functions/methods to implement repeated operations:

Pretty much anything you find yourself doing more than one time you should write a function to do. If you're lucky (or good) there will be a way to convert that function into a more "data-driven" approach:

```
def reformat_date_field(self, df, fieldname, format='%Y-%m-%d'):
    df[fieldname] = pd.to_datetime(df[fieldname], format=format)

reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['dad'], 'ADMIT_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['dad'], 'DIS_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['pc'], 'SE_END_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['pc'], 'SE_START_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['nacrs'], 'ARRIVE_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['pin'], 'DSPN_DATE')
reformat_date_field(self.dataframes['reg'], 'PERS_REAP_END_RSN_DATE')
```

Which becomes:

```
date_fields = (('dad', 'ADMIT_DATE'), ('dad', 'DIS_DATE'), ('pc', 'SE_END_DATE'),
               ('pc', 'SE_START_DATE'), ('nacrs', 'ARRIVE_DATE'), ('pin', 'DISP_DATE'),
               ('reg', 'PERS_REAP_END_RSN_DATE'))

for df, field in date_fields:
    reformat_date_field(self.dataframes[df], field)
```

(Or possibly some other data format that makes your life easy.)

The idea is to (1) make it clear what is happening by calling a named function; and (2) make it easy to extend or modify the list of fields by storing them as data instead of function calls.

Comment: You don't show what the tag classes do. But it seems like they're very close to creating boolean columns in the dataframes, or maybe taking boolean columns as input. I'd suggest looking in that direction to see if there isn't some low-hanging fruit to be picked.

Comment: For example, I need to make a date_tag which is similar to what you said but in 0 or 1, that is derived from if the record date is or isn't falling in an expected date range, then I have an icd_tag which is by screening 25 different diagnostic variables to see if any contains any element from a set of target icd codes. Then I retain patients if date_tag==icd_tag==1. Should I create separate helper functions, then add the function call in PatientDataAnalysis class?

Comment: It seems like this is the real "meat" of your analysis. So no. The PatientDataAnalysis class is the "skeleton" of the analysis. The particular details that talk about diabetes between 18 and 100 are not generic, but specific. So they would go in a specific subclass.

Comment: Also, instead of making a 0/1 tag, could you make a true/false tag, and then just do `in_group = df[df.date_tag & df.icd_tag]` ?

Comment: Using boolean does look a lot cleaner. The only thing is, I am interested to aggregate into unique patients. For example, if a patient has `date_tag==icd_tag==1` on 3 occurrences of hospitalization, summing it (from 0/1) allows me to characterize this patient to have 3 hospitalizations.

Comment: I am new to design pattern, and thanks for suggesting the template method pattern, it seems very powerful and relevant to my needs. I wonder for data visualization, say I normally need to present some basic descriptive stats and also statistical testing, but each project is somewhat different in terms of the exact stats, is template method also a good approach for this? So for the entire project, should I create one template method for patient creation, one for analysis, and one for data visualization etc?